# Erro ao acessar instância do objeto através da interface

Tags: c#, testes, .net-core, repository, moq

Estou fazendo testes unitários para C# usando o framework MOQ e estou utilizando EF core para acesso a dados. Estou escrevendo um método de teste para uma de minhas classes de repositório, a minha classe de repositório espera no construtor uma instância do meu ApplicationDbContext.

Dessa forma, tenho os seguintes arquivos:

```
IpplicationDbContext.cs
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
}


ApplicationDbContext.cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<ContactModel> Contact { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LoginModel> Login { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserModel> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRoleModel> UserRole { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleModel> Role { get; set; }        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactMap());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LoginMap());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserMap());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserRoleMap());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleMap());
    }
}
```

Até aqui tudo certo, eu criei a interface IApplicationDbContext.cs e implementei ela na minha classe ApplicationDbContext.cs, na interface IApplicationDbContext.cs eu tenho somente uma assinatura e a classe DbContext.cs já possui esse método implementado, dessa forma a classe ApplicationDbContext.cs passa a implementar o método pelo fato de herdar de DbContext.

O problema entra quando eu não consigo acessar a instância do objeto de IApplicationDbContext.cs mesmo tendo implementando em uma classe e fazendo o mapeamento da injeção de dependência. Método onde faço o mapeamento das injeções:

```
 public static IServiceCollection GetInjectionConfig(this IServiceCollection services) =>
            services
                .GetApplicationDbContextConfig()
                .GetTokenConfig()
                .GetEmailConfig()
                .GetValidationsConfig()
                .GetServicesConfig()
                .GetRepositoriesConfig();

    private static IServiceCollection GetApplicationDbContextConfig(this IServiceCollection services) =>
            services
                .AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>())
```

Em meu método de teste está sendo acusado o seguinte erro:
**cannot convert from 'Hospital.WebApi.Domain.Interfaces.ApplicationDbContext.IApplicationDbContext' to 'Hospital.WebApi.Infra.Data.Context.ApplicationDbContext'**

Método de teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é estranho, porque eu estou seguindo o padrão, de criar um mock através de uma interface e depois acessar o objeto desse mock (classe que implementa a interface), e conforme mencionado, eu criei a interface, implementei ela no meu AplicationDbContext, fiz o mapeamento e mesmo assim não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Não é mais fácil configurar o seu EF pra usar um banco em memória ou sqlite?

Comment: como o @BrunoWarmling comentou, mockar o DbContext não é facil, e usar um inmemory database funciona bem e é o mais simples. Instale o package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` e use ele para fazer isso. Basicamente seria algo como `var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<IApplicationDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("NomeDaSuaConfigComAStringDeConexao").Options` e depois `var dbContext  = new IApplicationDbContext(options)`

Comment: Nesse caso os testes não vai ficar dependentes do banco né? vai ser tipo o que eu tentei fazer ali, mas de outra forma? Porque não quero deixar os testes presos no banco, tipo, não quero que nenhum teste chegue até o banco real. Perguntando porque vi que você mencionou que devo colocar o nome de minha config com a string de conexão.

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversos providers necessários pra fazer o ApplicationDbContext funcionar desta forma, acho que essa abordagem não é a melhor, a menos que seja extremamente necessária.

Uma forma mais fácil é adotar a solução InMemory. A Microsoft implementou exatamente para este propósito.

Este link abaixo contém a documentação explicando como realizar os testes InMemory:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/

Tem bastante conteúdo sobre o assunto disponível.

Se ainda assim, quiser continuar com esta abordagem e acreditando que o restante está funcionando corretamente, dentro das suas classes de teste você utilizaria injeção de dependência da sua interface, algo como:

```
public class Teste
{
   private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context

   public Teste(IApplicationDbContext context)
   {
     _context = context;
   }
}
```

Depois, para fazer o mock do seu context:

```
var contextMock = new Mock<IApplicationDbContext>();
contextMock.Setup(x=> x.Set<ContactModel>()).Returns(contextMock.Object);
```